# Any chance to survive after "Apple Developer Program membership will be terminated" message?

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

I've got *"your Apple Developer Program account has been **flagged for removal**"* message on the 3rd May 2019. On 15th May 2019, I've got the *"your Apple Developer Program membership **will be terminated**"* message. 
Apple does not share specific reasons for that decision, as usual.

However, as of 20th May the account is still active: I can access it and make changes.

Since the 15th of May I've removed from sale all apps that could have caused Apple's anger. I've disabled all corresponding In-App purchases. I've deleted most of the apps. I can't delete one of them because there's an In-App purchase with *"in Review"* status.

Is there still a chance for canceling the termination of my membership? How long does it usually take to terminate a membership?

Waiting for death is sort of worse than the death itself.

Comment: So how did it go? Do you still have your account?

Comment: No. It was active for some time. Then I submitted an app update and got the final termination message shortly after that. I think that app was the cause of termination. It was significantly redesigned, but Apple apparently didn’t care.

Answer (score 1):

Only Apple can answer your queries.

> Is there still a chance for canceling the termination of my membership? How long does it usually take to terminate a membership?

There's no documented rules for this, and it's totally upto the concerned team(s) at Apple to take calls. As far as one can understand, it is taken up on a case by case basis.

To get answers to any of your queries, it's best to contact Apple Developer Support:

- [Support - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/support/)
- [Worldwide Telephone Support - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/)

Comment: Trying to do this. No success with Telephone support so far. They redirected to offline support